# Storing JWT in a cookie

Tags: setcookie, httponly, cookie-httponly

Okay, so the idea was to use a `HttpOnly` cookie to store the JWT in the browser to authenticate and persist session.

Backend: `http://<project>.<company>.test/api` (internal test)

The problem is that the browser won't send the cookie to the backend using `fetch` (yes, I'm using the `credentials: 'include'` option).

- I'm testing the frontend on localhost
- If I use `HttpOnly`, the cookie cannot be accessed from within the client-side javascript code - this is good
- I can't set it to `Secure`, because the cookie has to be sent over **HTTPS**
- I can't set the `Domain` property, because "Setting cookies for another domain is not possible."
- I'd have to set the `SameSite` option to `None`, but if the cookie’s attribute SameSite is None the cookie has to be set with flag `Secure` - so we're right back at the `Secure` "problem"

It sounded good and everywhere they say that storing the jwt in a http-only cookie is the safest bet, but I can't use it in a local test, nor in our internal test. What am I missing? Any tips or alternatives?